# 3D Reconstruction from several images

Tags: python, camera, computer-vision, 3d-reconstruction

i'm sorry if someone already answered at this question, but I'm looking at every page on the Internet not founding the perfect answer for my problem. I need to reconstruct a 3D model from multiple 2D images. The fact is that i already have the images and i don't have info about the camera. I just know that it has been used one camera that has been rotated around the object. In order to reconstruct the 3D shape of the object i need to establish the camera matrix but i don't have any idea how to do it. I'm using ORB feature detection treating two images like a stereo view to establish a corrispondance and find the Fundamental Matrix and the Homography but i can't proceed to find camera parameters. I'm using python and OpenCV. Thanks in advance.

Comment: this is a significant area of research in machine learning. there's unlikely to be a simple answer.

Comment: You could have a look into auto-calibration methods.

Answer (score 0):

its been a while since youve asked this question but you can extract the focal length of an image from its Exif tags, It will work only if the images you have are in JPEG format. The optical centers can be approximated as width/2 and height/2, heres a good material about  the same: http://phototour.cs.washington.edu/focal.html

Reading Exif can be done using a plethora of packages/libraries available, one such example in Python is : https://pypi.org/project/ExifRead/

Note : Exif data of focal lengths are in mm, you might have to convert it to pixels beforehand by using the sensor width value(also encoded in Exif tag).

F(pixels) = F(mm) x ImageWidth(pixel)/SensorWidth(mm)

Once you have Focal lengths, Cx, Cy determined you can fit these into Camera matrix K and proceed via SFM/MVS or Stereo Reconstruction based on the images you have at hand.